# Is AWS S3 CORS policy at file level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to apply a CORS policy to my S3 bucket, and what I am observing is that, if at any point of time, I modify the CORS policy, the older files that were uploaded to S3 still do not use the new CORS policy. For e.g.

1. I created a S3 bucket "X"
2. Added the following CORS policy -

   ```
   <CORSConfiguration>
   <CORSRule>
       <AllowedOrigin>https://app1.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
       <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
       <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
       <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```
3. Successfully uploaded a file a.jpeg from my application that is hosted on `https://app1.example.com`. I was also able to do a GET and a DELETE.
4. Now I need to use the same S3 bucket for another one of my hosted apps, say app2. So I modified the CORS policy to -

   ```
   <CORSConfiguration>
   <CORSRule>
       <AllowedOrigin>https://app1.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
       <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
       <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
       <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   <CORSRule>
       <AllowedOrigin>https://app2.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
       <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
       <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
       <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
   </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
   ```
5. Now when I try to GET the file a.jpeg from `https://app2.example.com`, I still see the below error

   ```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load <S3 URL>. Origin https://app2.mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
   ```
6. However if I try to upload a new file b.jpeg from `https://app2.mydomain.com`, everything works as expected.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention this earlier, but we have a CloudFront CDN in front of our S3 bucket, but I cannot find any config related to setting CORS policy in the Cloudfront config.

Is there a way by which we can enforce the new CORS policy on previously uploaded files as well? Or is there some other way to make this work?

Comment: Used protocol:// instead of https:// coz I wasn't being allowed to post more than 2 links with below 10 reputation.

Comment: Try surrounding those https strings with `\`` backticks, with an edit, please.  That *should* cause them to be interpreted as opaque string literals instead of links.  Also "example.com" is preferred, since I assume the domain you've used isn't your actual domain, and may be somebody else's.

Comment: S3 CORS policy is bucket-level... but S3 also supports a single wildcard in the allowed origin (e.g. `*.example.com`)... but is it possible your browser cached the preflight response from before the change was made?  Can you capture the response headers S3 is actually returning?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I've modified the description as you suggested. Our security team doesn't approve of using wild cards for supported domains and each domain must be added separately. I tried doing the same flow as I have described in private browsing mode, and I still see the same issue. So I doubt that it is related to browser caching.

Comment: Aha... CloudFront.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors ...The docs are a little vague on what happens if you do nothing, but it seems like to me you'd want to forward `Origin:` and the other two headers to S3.

Comment: I got the Cloudfront config reviewed and we are already forwarding the Origin header.