# How to update files in S3 bucket with new CORS rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

So I'm trying to add CORS rule to my S3 bucket. I've set up the rules, but the Access-Allow-Origin headers aren't showing up in the response.

I've tried searching and found a user with similar issue, but there weren't any answers. ([Is AWS S3 CORS policy at file level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300568/is-aws-s3-cors-policy-at-file-level))

It seems like once you update the CORS rule, it doesn't get applied to the existing files in the bucket, but when I add a new file to the bucket, the CORS rules get applied to the new file.

I've been researching for 3 days now and had no luck. Anyone know how to solve this issue

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a local caching issue?  That's what is sounds like.